# How to find the saddle point of a complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis

This must be really simple because solutions never seem to contain any working used to find saddle points, they are just listed, but I'm lost.

Take for example the Hankel function;

$$ H_{\nu}^{(2)}  = \frac{1}{i \pi} \int^{0 - i\epsilon}_{-\infty - i\epsilon} exp\left(\frac{x}{2}\left[ z - \frac{1}{z} \right]\right) \frac{dz}{z^{\nu +1}}$$

I believe that this has saddle points at $\pm i$ but I have no idea how to work that out. How do I work out the saddle points of this function? More generally how should I go about working out the saddle points of any complex function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The saddle point is a method to evaluate the asymptotic expansion of an integral
$$ g(x)= \int_C \exp[x f(z)] h(z) dz $$
for $x\to \infty$. For that you have to find points $z^*$ such that 
$$ f'(z_*) =0.$$
Those points are called saddle points and deforming the contour $C$ to cross those points (in the correct direction) allows you to estimate $g(x)$ by evaluating $f(z)$ and $h(z)$ for $z$ close to $z_*$.

For your specific case, you have $f(z) = z- z^{-1}$ and thus the saddle points are given by 
$$ f'(z^*)= 1+ z_*^{-2} =0,$$
i.e. $z_* = \pm i$.

I am not sure what you mean with the saddle point of any complex function though.

Comment: thanks, you gave me the answer I didn't know I needed :)